# CMMotionManager data 'Jumps' after iOS 10 update

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, gyroscope, cmmotionmanager

I'm developing an app that uses CMMotionManager, and prior iOS 10, the data from manager was stable. After iOS 10 update it started 'jumping' (data for the moment *t+1* is times bigger than data for moment *t*, and at moment *t+2* it returns to stable state).
I'm using *attitude* property of CMDeviceMotion, and reference frame *CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical*.

What can I do to stabilize data from Manager?

Comment: Seems like a bug in the iOS internals. Other people are mentioning it also and I am experiencing the same problem. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52145 and https://openradar.appspot.com/27787269

Comment: Thanks.. I guess we are just waiting for Apple on this one..

Comment: Almost a month later and there is still no answer from Apple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely an iOS 10 bug. Unfortunately apple does not even want to talk about it although it represents a serious bug for all augmented reality apps. Many developers have reported it and no one has a clue on how to solve it.

The most interesting thread is : [forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52145 : CMMotionManager incorrect behavior](http://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52145)

However I would like to point out that you can only access this thread using it's url. If you simply go to apple developer forums and do a search using the exact same title, the thread will not appear in the results.

Apparently this is the way apple found to hide it's mistakes. Shame, shame...